# Does react always create a new object on state change?

Tags: reactjs

I need something like follows to work.

```
let oldState
this.setState(state => {
    oldState = state
    if (smth) {
        return null
    }
    return {show: true}
  },
  () => {
    if (this.state === oldState) {
        return
    }
    // do some extra stuff
  }
  )
```

The question is if I can rely on react always creating a new object if update has happened, and not otherwise. Any known guarantees? If `{show: true}` was reached and the state `show` is `true`, would the object stay the same or a new one will be created?

Comment: You are not updating object rather passing in an Object whose property gets consumed internally by react in your case `show` and its value gets updated in new state

Comment: You are creating a new reference when you return {show: true} . Not sure about old react, but in react-hooks, after the initial call, it doesn't rerender if the same reference sent.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can [treat state as immutable](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state)–it will create a new object upon update. Additionally, the callback passed as the second parameter to `setState` will not run until the scheduled `setState` operation is run.

Comment: I see, so the state is immutable but is not guaranteed a new object is created.